# Como pegar a posição de um determinado elemento em uma lista através de um attr especifico?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma UL com algum itens. Por exemplo

```
<ul class='ordemQuestoes'>
    <li idquestao="28" >Questao 28</li>
    <li idquestao="2" >Questao 2</li>
    <li idquestao="17" >Questao 17</li>
</ul>
```

Quando vou salvar uma questão preciso gravar no banco a ordem que está dentre as 3. E esse número pode variar.

Na hora de salvar eu tenho em mãos o idquestao, então como eu faço pra através do idquestao 17 por exemplo eu conseguir retornar 3, de terceira posição?

Não consegui ainda pensar numa lógica para conseguir esse resultado.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No jQuery, [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) retorna a posição do elemento dentro do elemento pai, contando a partir de zero.

Se você já tem o `<li>` como um objeto jQuery, basta pedir o *index* dele:

```
var posicao = liDezessete.index(); // posicao será 2
```

Se precisa mesmo chegar no índice a partir do valor do atributo, dá pra fazer com um dos [seletores de atributo](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/):

```
var posicao = $('li[idquestao=17]').index();
```

```js
var posicao = $('li[idquestao=17]').index();
alert(posicao)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='ordemQuestoes'>
    <li idquestao="28" >Questao 28</li>
    <li idquestao="2" >Questao 2</li>
    <li idquestao="17" >Questao 17</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ótimo, só tive que adicionar + 1 ao resultado!